# Customize AWS Amplify authentication UI for iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to customize the logo on the signIn page using the following:

```
AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance()
    .showSignIn(navigationController: self.navigationController!,
                      signInUIOptions: SignInUIOptions(
                            canCancel: false,
                            logoImage: UIImage(named: "MyCustomLogo"),
                            backgroundColor: UIColor.black)) { (result, 
err) in
                            //handle results and errors               
}
```

However, the default logo still appears but the background does turn black. I have MyCustomLogo in the project but it just does not take. I'm fairly new to Apple development so I'm sure I'm missing something simple or maybe I'm not. I just need help please :)

Comment: Being worked on:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1115

Answer (score 0):

I am able to add a custom logo to my Amplify Drop-In UI using the iOS SDK. You have to be sure to add your logo assets in the `Assets.xcassets` folder for your project to know where to look and override. Also, I presume you named your logo `MyCustomLogo` as you show in your code block above. You don't need to specify `.png`.